# Wordpress Repeating Meta Glitch

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am running into a strange issue on the repeating meta plugin I created. Everything works fine (saving to database, retreating data, adding meta sections, removing meta sections) except for one thing which I will explain in detail. Here is what needs to be taken into consideration:

- I have 3 saved meta sections with three fields of data saved within each section
- Deleting the first or second section removes all data from all three sections when saving the page in WordPress(bad)
- Deleting the third section and then saving the WordPress page will only delete the third section, the first two are still saved(good)
- Deleting the second section and then creating a new section, and then saving in WordPress will remove all sections (section 1,2,3) EXCEPT for the section that was added after deleting the second section (section 4).

Here is my JS code that runs the delete:

```
     jQuery(document).on('click','.removeMeta',function(){
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();
        var index = metaBoxes.indexOf(parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('slideId')));
        if (index > -1) {
            metaBoxes.splice(index, 1);
        }
        jQuery('#metaBoxArray').val(metaBoxes.join());
        sortRepMeta();
    });
        function sortRepMeta() {
        jQuery('.meta-box-text').text(function(i, oldVal) {
        return "Meta Section "+(i+1);
        });
    }
```

Here is a snippet of the PHP save function for the repeating meta sections:

```
if( $_POST ) {
    $data = array();
    $full_meta_array = array();
     foreach (explode(',', $_POST['metaBoxArray']) as $key => $i) {
        $meta_box = array();

        if(empty($_POST['repTextArea'][$i])){
            $full_meta_array = array();
        }else{
            $meta_box['repTextArea'] = $_POST['repTextArea'][$i];
                    $meta_box['repTextField'] = $_POST['repTextField'][$i];
                    $meta_box['image'] = $_POST['image'][$i];

            $full_meta_array[] = $meta_box;
        }
    }
     $data = $full_meta_array;

        //  var_dump($data);
    // Update the meta field in the database.
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'repMetaArray', $data );
```

Is there anything wrong with the code above? I am not sure where to look at to solve this issue. I thought that the JS would be emptying out the data in the meta sections on delete, but when I ran a var_dump on the array that stores the all meta section info, it stated that all the fields were still populated. Let me know if there is any other info that needs to be provided.

EDIT: Where the loop begins to echo the code that generates the meta boxes:

```
$rep_meta_array = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'repMetaArray', true );   

foreach ($rep_meta_array as $key => $meta_box) {
    $jsMeta[] = $meta_box_count = $key;
```

Where metaBoxes and metaCount is defined:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var metaCount = <?php echo count($rep_meta_array) +   1; ?>;
        var metaBoxes = [<?php if(!empty($jsMeta)){echo implode(',',$jsMeta);}?>];
        jQuery('#metaBoxArray').val(metaBoxes.join());
    </script>
```

Comment: What is `metaBoxes`, where is it defined? Maybe show more code and/or the markup.

Comment: I added an edit that shows the code for where metaBoxes and metaCount is defined

Comment: First, you're building `metaBoxArray` with `metaBoxes.join()` and converting it back to array with `explode(',', $_POST['metaBoxArray'])`, so maybe it's just that it splits the text at unexpected positions. Use the same separator in both `join()` and `explode()` and use a character that won't be found anywhere else in the string (like `|` or `\``) and/or validate that no element has it before joining them.